# Removing all occurrences of empty string in a dictionary of arrays

Tags: python, data-structures

The title is complicated, I admit, but the task is intuitive.

Consider the simplified version of my dictionary data:

```
{ 
"Object" : ['Circle', '', ' ', 'Rectangle' '']
"x" : [1, 2, 3, 1, 4]
"y" : [2, 1, 0, 3, 4]
}
```

Notice that index 1, 2, 4 of the array for key = "object" corresponds to an empty string. My task is to remove all occurrences of the values of such indices, so that the final output is:

```
{ 
"Object" : ['Circle', 'Rectangle'],
"x" : [1, 1],
"y" : [2, 3]
}.
```

My current pseudocode to the problem is as follows, assuming the name of the data is dic:

```
i = 0

while i < len(d['text']):
  while not d['text'][i]:
    for key, arr in d.items():
      print(key)
      d[key] = d[key].pop(i)
  i += 1
```

The current problem with the code is index out of range.

My gut feelings insist that this is a barbaric way to address the problem, unforgivable by the pythonic standards.

Comment: _It does not even work_ -> What exactly does that mean? And please fix the indentation of your code and make it a [mre]

Comment: Also: Mind that an "empty" string usually is just `''`. You seem to also want to omit string containing whitespace only.
Also: Pay attention to the case sensitivity of almost all modern programming languages. `"Object"` is not the same as `"object"`.

Comment: @OcasoProtal Thanks, edited accordingly, and I will update my progress

Comment: @Pythocrates Great point. I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple almost-one-liner:

```
my_dict = {"Object" : ['Circle', '', ' ', 'Rectangle', ''], "x" : [1, 2, 3, 1, 4], "y" : [2, 1, 0, 3, 4]}

remove_inds = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_dict['Object']) if x.strip() == '']
new_dict = {k: [v[i] for i in range(len(my_dict['Object'])) if i not in remove_inds] for k, v in my_dict.items()}

print(new_dict)
# {'Object': ['Circle', 'Rectangle'], 'x': [1, 1], 'y': [2, 3]}
```

Comment: I will, definitely, after applying the solutions to the original problem. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to first find the indices of the "non-empty" strings:

```
indices = [i for i, o in enumerate(dirty['Object']) if o]
```

or, based on your definition of an empty string:

```
indices = [i for i, o in enumerate(dirty['Object']) if o.strip()]
```

Then you can create a new dictionary using these indices:

```
clean = {
    'Object': [dirty['Object'][i] for i in indices],
    'x': [dirty['x'][i] for i in indices],
    'y': [dirty['y'][i] for i in indices],
}
```

or using @ShlomiF's more clever approach:

```
clean = {key: [dirty[key][i] for i in indices] for key in dirty}
```

BTW: I named the original dict `dirty`.

Comment: It seems like I have not been familiar with dictionary. Thanks for sharing a useful approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
index = 0
found_empty = False
size_of_array = len(dic['Object'])
while index < size_of_array: # key = "object"
    dic['Object'][index] = dic['Object'][index].replace(' ','')
    if not dic["Object"][index]: # if the string is empty
        found_empty = True
        for key in dic.keys(): # iterate over all keys of the dictionary
            dic[key].pop(index) # remove element at the index, re-assign array
        size_of_array = len(dic['Object'])
    if not found_empty:
        index += 1
    found_empty = False
```

In order to pop the elements you must keep track of empty element to do perfect indexing. I would suggest to do this as it is exactly according to your logic.

Comment: Thank you for the time and guidance. It was a  great refresh about the topic with your code.